# Option to prevent default bounty reward if I'm not satisfied with receiving answer

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I put a bounty on this question: [Implementing unit of work in a WCF service with Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988512/implementing-unit-of-work-in-a-wcf-service-with-autofac)

Before doing so I've investigated quite much on my own to try to find a way to do it. I've extended WCF in several ways in the past (customized error handling, custom authentication and authorization, IoC support in my [Griffin.Container](https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.container)).

So not getting any reasonable answers (it's a bit strange that he answered his own question when his answer to not fulfill his own requirements) I wonder why I have to award the bounty?

I do not want the bounty back. But I do not want to award it to the current answer.

**Suggestion:**

Couldn't there be a bounty flag option too? So that a moderator can take a look at the question and my motivation to why I don't want to award it. Just as I can flag an answer as "Not an answer" with a motivation

**Edit**

The bounty went away? Someone did something? :)

Comment: you don't have to award the bounty, however, any answers with +2 score posted after the bounty started may be auto-awarded. See the [faq#bounty], etc.

Comment: It was the auto-awarding that I didn't want to happen. Fortunately  there was only one vote.

Answer (score 3):

As Jeff said, the bounty is auto-awarded if there's a new answer with +2 score or higher.

I think the idea is that the +2 score is a good way to distinguish between a worthwhile answer and a poor (or outright incorrect) one. I instinctively agree with your desire to keep control over who gets a bounty; OTOH, if I went to the trouble of finding an answer to a featured question, and it got a nice score - i.e. was appreciated by others, which is entirely nontrivial on most questions that need the push of a bounty! - I'd be kinda annoyed if the bounty-setter decided he didn't like my answer or my user avatar or whatnot, and could avert it somehow.

If there's an extreme case, you can flag the question or the answer for mod attention (you've got room there to explain precisely what the issue is), or bring the case up here on Meta. I don't think this scenario necessitates a whole additional flag mechanism for bounties.

Comment: bear in mind it's effectively +3 since the question owner can downvote an answer from +2 to +1 single-handedly if necessary